# Incorrect Window size on flutter desktop when having multiple pages

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter desktop application on linux. I want to have two app pages, each containing buttons to navigate back and forth between the pages.

On startup, I am using the [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window) package to declare the window size. This resizes the window on startup to the desired size. Code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bitsdojo_window/bitsdojo_window.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: FirstPage(),
  ));
  doWhenWindowReady(() {
    final win = appWindow;
    const initialSize = Size(300, 600);
    win.minSize = initialSize;
    win.size = initialSize;
    win.alignment = Alignment.center;
    win.title = "Desktop application";
    win.show();
  });
}
```

However, when I add navigation to the Elevated Button within the page, the window does not launch with the correct size. Specifically this happens when I add the `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()));` action OnPressed. The code for the build function is as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        appBar: const MyAppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              // Connect Button
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()));
                  },
                  child: const Text('Next'),),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

- Why does this happen?
- Is it possible to ensure that the sizing is retained even after adding other pages?
- Is there an alternative method of achieving and retaining a specific window size?